# Extract LDA model values into distribution matrix efficiently

Tags: python, matrix, gensim, lda

I am using gensim's [lda implementation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html) to create a document topic model distribution. I have a model `lda` trained

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(data)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in data]
num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
num_topics = 150
lda = LdaMulticore(corpus=corpus, num_topics=num_topics, id2word=dictionary, workers=num_cores, alpha=1e-4, eta=5e-1,
              minimum_probability=0.0)
```

I want to extract a distribution matrix of size N * M where N is the number of documents in the corpus, and M is the number of topics. Each row therefore would represent a document, and each column would represent a topic. These distributions are already available in the `lda` model variable e.g.

```
lda
>>> [[(0,0.01),(1,0.23),(2,1e-7)],
    [(0,0.91),(1,0.067),(2,0.38)]]
```

where the above represents a simple example if we had 2 documents and 3 topics (0,1,2). So `lda` is a list of list of tuples, where each list is a document, the first element in the tuple is the topic id and the second element is the topic contribution to that document.

What I have done so far

```
# approach 1
distributions = np.array( [[tup[1] for tup in lst] for lst in lda[corpus]] )
# approach 2 (about 3X slower than approach 1)
distributions = np.array(lda[corpus])[:,:,1]
```

The problem is, for a dataset with 300k documents and 150 topics, creating the `distributions` matrix using approach 1 takes over 10 minutes.

Ultimately, I want to create this matrix to feed into a function which calculates document similarity (comparing the first row / document of the matrix to all other rows / documents). If there is a way to directly feed the learned `lda` model values into the function, that would be great as it would save time on creating the redundant matrix. If not, is there a more efficient way to create the `distributions` matrix?

For reference, the document comparison function into which the `distributions` matrix is fed is

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
from scipy.stats import entropy
def jsd(mat):
    mat = normalize(mat, axis=1, norm='l1')
    p = mat[0,None].T # just comparing first row to all other rows
    q = mat[0:].T
    m = 0.5*(p + q)
    return 0.5*(entropy(p,m) + entropy(q,m))
```